# Lots of image view with dynamically display images

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to do `UIScrollView` with a lot of small `UIImageView`, and i want to display immediately blank scroll view. And then when it's ready load images into `UIImageViews`. 
For example when i have to download some part from the server i'm using:
`connectionDidFinishLoading` with `NSURLConnection` but here i don't want to download online images, i have it in my app, but don't want to draw all in once in `viewDidLoad`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [bddynamicgridviewcontroller](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bddynamicgridviewcontroller) link for UIImageView list in a row-dominated grid layout

Also refer [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for lazy loading of lots of images

take look at [UITables with Downloaded Images – Easy Asynchronous Code](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/) link

Comment: "Easy Asynchronous Code" using NSURLConnection. Can i use it for local files?

Comment: u can use as only matters is uiimage data as where it comes from when coming from server or from local it takes time to display and that will be handled by Asynchronous Downloaded Images

Answer (score 0):

To start with, use [`AQGridView`](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) - it's similar to `UITableView` but allows multiple columns per row (i.e. a grid of photos). If you download the source code it has examples of how to use it for what you want.

As for showing the images as they download, one way is to use [`FLImageView`](https://github.com/anoopr/fully-loaded). Again, download the source code and add it to your project and then instead of using a `UIImageView` in each `AQGridViewCell` use a `FLImageView` then call `loadImageAtURL:placeholderImage:` or `loadImageAtURLString:placeholderImage:` when you load the image. This also allows you to display a standard placeholder image while images are downloading.

Like a standard `UITableView`, cells for `AQGridView` will only be created as needed (i.e. only the ones on screen or almost on screen) and cells are reused so it will be nice and fast.